# comment in algorithmic on a line beginning with if

Tags: algorithmic

I'm working with `algorithmic` to create some pseudo-code with comments. With a macro found on this site (see header), comments will be aligned on the right, which is wonderful.

However, I don't get it how to have a comment on a line beginning with `\IF`.

Below is a SSCCE, that shows a workaround.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{%
  \hfill\#\ \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \STATE $math$ \COMMENT{comment 1}
      \IF{$moremath$}
        \STATE \COMMENT{comment 2 one line up please}
        \STATE $lastmath$
      \ENDIF
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This modification does not work, pdflatex chokes up on `\STATE $lastmath$`.

```
  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \STATE $math$ \COMMENT{comment 1}
      \IF{$moremath$} \COMMENT{comment 2 on line 2 please} %\STATE removed, won't work!
        \STATE $lastmath$
      \ENDIF
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
```

I use `pdflatex`. How can I modify my code to have the comments in line 1 and 2, rather than having comment 2 on a separate line (workaround)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments on if statements are to be provided as on optional argument to `\IF` rather than via the `\COMMENT` command. See section 3.12 of the documentation, this also applies to `\ELSIF`, `\ELSE`, `\WHILE`, `\FOR`, `\FORALL`, `\REPEAT` and `\LOOP`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{%
  \hfill\#\ \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}  % patch def of algorithmic environment
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\algorithmic}{\addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin} }{\addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \STATE {$math$} \COMMENT{comment 1}
      \IF[comment 2 on line 2]{$moremath$}
        \STATE $lastmath$ \COMMENT{comm 3}
      \ENDIF
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

*Update* a spurious space in the definition of the `ALC@g` environment inside the `algorthmic` environment cased misalignemnt of the comments.  Patch added above to code.

Comment: inconsistency squared, yay! But works flawlessly, thank you very much.

Comment: comments #1 and #2 are not vertically well aligned. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @pluton Well spotted!  It turns out to be a spurious space in the algorthimic package code.  Patch now added above.

Comment: Nice. I'll contact the maintainer of the package.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for pointing this out and for spotting theh problem. I (belatedly) fixed this with a new release of the package: https://github.com/rbrito/algorithms/releases/tag/2017.11.08