# Comment in algorithmic on a line beginning with if, and using uncover/visible

Tags: beamer, algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying to modify [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133158/comment-in-algorithmic-on-a-line-beginning-with-if), into the following one :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{%
  \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE $x := 1$ \visible<2->{\COMMENT{$x_1 \in [1;1]$}}
    \WHILE[\visible<2->{\COMMENT{whatever}}]{{$x < 10000$}
      \STATE $x := x+1$     \COMMENT{bla}
      \ENDWHILE
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I just want the comment of the if block to appear on a second and different slide. That's why I used `\uncover`, but this isn't accepted by `pdflatex` during compilation.

The **error** is `! Undefined control sequence.` (I can paste the log if you prefer)

How can I change this ?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT** : the best option might be using algorithmicx. Thus, comments of a `\While` have to be pushed in the end of the same line, and not something like `\WHILE[]`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the precise error here?

Comment: Thanks ! I edited my answer. Do you want me to paste the whole log ?

Comment: I think, you're getting into trouble with verbatim content of the algorithm environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this requested? I am unsure, but sometimes it's better to use the `\only` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\algorithmiccomment[1]{%
  \eqparbox{COMMENT}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \only<1>{%
      \STATE $x := 1$
      \WHILE[]{$x < 10000$}
      \STATE $x := x+1$     \COMMENT{bla}
      \ENDWHILE
    }%
\only<2->{%
  \STATE $x := 1$ {\COMMENT{$x_1 \in [1;1]$}}
  \WHILE[\COMMENT{whatever}]{$x < 10000$}
  \STATE $x := x+1$     \COMMENT{bla}
  \ENDWHILE
}%
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is. But I hoped there was a way to modify only the comment within the while, and not copy/paste the whole code.

Comment: I checked : using algorithmicx is far easier in this case... Thanks for the help !